# JS change property in object constructor

Tags: javascript

How can I achieve that:

```
function Item(name, company) {
    this.name = name;
    [company] = 'Google';
}
var company = 'internet';
var test = new Item('someone', company);
```

`test.name` return `'someone'`.

`test.internet` should return `'Google'`.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: @Quentin: I'm looking for an example of using that in a constructor. Can't find a better dupe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Just like `name`, you need to assign the variable key to `this`.

```js
function Item(name, company) {
    this.name = name;
    this[company] = 'Google';
}
var company = 'internet';
var test = new Item('someone', company);

console.log(test.internet)
```